# How to fix Error 500 when sending a file in a Formdata?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need to send a file to my server I m using a FormData and I specified the headers, But I keep getting the same error: 500 which is not telling me a lot,
When I try to inspect the network in dev tools I see this message from the server:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/task/aws_lambda_powertools/event_handler/api_gateway.py", line
> 611, in _call_route
> return ResponseBuilder(self._to_response(route.func(**args)), route)   File "/var/task/routes/leads.py", line 47, in upload_files
> files_url, images_url = uploadFilesLeads(body, headers)   File "/var/task/services/leads.py", line 30, in uploadFilesLeads
> files, images = get_file_from_request_body(headers, body)   File "/var/task/repository/shared.py", line 25, in
> get_file_from_request_body
> "content-type": headers["Content-Type"], KeyError: 'Content-Type'

This is my post request :

```
const attchFiles = new FormData();
attchFiles.append("files", files);
const attachements = await axios.post(MyURL, attchFiles, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
});
console.log(attachements);
```

Comment: HTTP error 500 means there is an internal server error. Which means the error isn't generated by the request, but is thrown when your server throws an error. You'll have to check your servers code.

Comment: Well it's working with postman, which lead me to think that my request is causing the error, is that wrong to assume ?

Comment: Generally no, if you are sure you've used the same content and headers as in postman.

Comment: What server are you sending the request to? If it is your own, then most likely, there is going to be the issue. Probably you could provide the server log, or give us the backend code that handles the request?

Comment: unfortunately it is not my own server, the app is also serverless I should mention and I noticed this error in the response headers: x-cache: Error from cloudfront, So i m trying to search into that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appropriate headers:

```
headers: formData.getHeaders()
```

So in your case:

```
const attchFiles = new FormData();
attchFiles.append("files", files);
const attachements = await axios.post(MyURL, attchFiles, {
  headers: attachFiles.getHeaders()
});
console.log(attachements);
```

Indeed, you were missing the "boundary" header.